# How to fix textSelectedColor property in dropdownlist using Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5, flashdevelop

I am using `s:DropDownList` component in Flash Builder 4.6.

I have to set property `textSelectedColor` which is given in `mx:ComboBox` but not given in `s:DropDownList`.

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Creae a custom item renderer for the drop down